# Intuition behind $\mathcal{M}_g\cong\mathcal{T}(S)/\text{Mod}(S)$.

Tags: complex-analysis, riemann-surfaces

Let $S$ be a compact Riemann surface of genus $g$. The mapping class group $\text{Mod}(S)$, constitued by all homotopy classes of orientation-preserving diffeomorphisms, acts on $\mathcal{T}(S)$ (Teichmüller's space), by:
$$[h]\cdot[X,f]:=[X,f\circ h^{1}],$$
for all $[h]\in\text{Mod}(S)$.

The orbit space $\mathcal{T}(S)/\text{Mod}(S)$ is then naturally identified with $\mathcal{M}_g$, the moduli space of Riemann surfaces of genus $g$.

Why this is the case? Why would an orbit be identified with a biholomorphism class of Riemann surfaces?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Loosely speaking, in $T(S)$ you identify two marked Riemann surfaces when the markings $f_1$ and $f_2$ are homotopic to the identity in some sense (more precisely, when they are homotopic to a biholomorphism between $X_1$ and $X_2$).

So the same underlying (biholomorphism class of) Riemann surface $X$ can give you different points in $T(S)$ for different markings. But when you mod out by $Mod(S)$, those points are now the same in $T(S)/Mod(S)$. In other words, with your notations, in $T(S)/Mod(S)$ two points $[X_1,f_1]$ and $[X_2,f_2]$ are the same if and only if $X_1$ is biholomorphic to $X_2$.

Comment: Whether this explanation is satisfying might depend on the OP's definition of Teichmüller space. If they are defining it using hyperbolic structures, the connection to complex structures is less obvious.

Comment: This is exactly the definition I'm used to. Now it all makes sense! Thank you